# Postgresql query join only first row that match pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to add field **ovr.riga** that should be the first match from  many, so I make a subquery to get the **progressivo** list that should be considered, but postresql complain

> that more than a row is returned by subquery

```
SELECT
    ovr.progressivo,
    ovr.art_codice,
    ovr.descrizione1,
    ovr.descrizione2,
    ovr.riga
FROM ovr
WHERE ovr.progressivo = (
    SELECT progressivo
    FROM ovr
    WHERE
        ovr.art_codice ~~ '0034%'::text OR
        ovr.art_codice ~~ '0035%'::text OR
        ovr.art_codice ~~ '0036%'::text
    group by progressivo
)
```

the subquery alone run fine

Comment: Why do you have commas in the `from` clause?  If you only want one row, why not just use `limit 1`?

Comment: Is there only 1 match in ovr table? or 1 match for each ovt.progressivo = ovr.progressivo??

Comment: Don't mix old, implicit JOIN syntax and new, modern explicit JOIN syntax - it's just too confusing. Stick to explicit JOIN syntax all the way  - it's easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Quote: "the subquery alone run fine". So how many records does it return? One or more?

Comment: `group by progressivo` makes no sense here and you should remove it from your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `=` with `in`:

```
where ovr.progressivo in (
```

If you want only the (whatever) first:

```
select distinct on (ovr.progressivo)
    ovr.progressivo,
    ovr.art_codice,
    ovr.descrizione1,
    ovr.descrizione2,
    ovr.riga
from ovr
where ovr.progressivo in (
    select progressivo
    from ovr
    where
        ovr.art_codice ~~ '0034%'::text or
        ovr.art_codice ~~ '0035%'::text or
        ovr.art_codice ~~ '0036%'::text
    group by progressivo
)
order by ovr.progressivo
```

If you have a criteria to what is first add it to the `order by` clause

Comment: No this is not equivalent. The IN query would get you all records that have a progressivo for which also exist certain art_codices. Your query gets you all records with those art_codices only.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ok fixed

Answer (score 0):

The "as is" query contains "where ovr.progressivo = ( ... )" where the subquery produces multiple rows. The equal operator cannot evaluate a list of values, but the IN operator can.

Try using IN

```
SELECT
      ovr.progressivo
    , ovr.art_codice
    , ovr.descrizione1
    , ovr.descrizione2
    , ovr.riga
FROM ovr
WHERE ovr.progressivo IN (   --<<<<<<< change = to IN
            SELECT
                  progressivo
            FROM ovr
            WHERE ovr.art_codice -- '0034%'::text 
               OR ovr.art_codice -- '0035%'::text
               OR ovr.art_codice -- '0036%'::text
            GROUP BY
                  progressivo
      )
;
```

If that resolves the error then you need to decide which of the result rows you want and control the result by using ORDER BY and LIMIT 1